# Which EF Core EntityType Configurations are important if I dont use EF Migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core

The documentation does not cover this so I give a try here.

Do I need builder informations like

```
    // Navigation Indexes
    builder.HasIndex(p => p.QuestionId);
    builder.HasIndex(p => p.UserId);
```

if I use a database first approach and dont use migrations?
Are those informations maybe important for the query generations?

Which builder declarations are important?

Comment: I assume you are using a tool to create the mappings? But certainly indexes are not needed for query generation.

Comment: Hi @ErikEJ thanks for all your work for the EF Community. I use a database first approach and dont need EF Core Migrations.

Comment: Are you facing any issues with the extra mappings?